# TypeError: can't pickle NotImplementedType objects (in keras, python)

Tags: python, keras, pickle

I was doing deep run using Keras.
However, the following error occurred in the process of storing the model after learning.

> TypeError: can't pickle NotImplementedType objects

I had no problem when I ran the same code in another directory.

The code below is the portion of the code that is causing the error.

```
.... 

model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs = 3, batch_size =500)


scores = model.evaluate(x_test,y_test)

#print("%s:.2f%%"%(model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

model.save('/disk3/seaice/seaice_keras_model2.h5')
```

Is the type error of pickle appearing in the storage method inside the keras?

It's also the same environment, but I don't know why it works differently in different directories.

I'd appreciate it if you could provide me with a solution to this problem.

Comment: I found some interesting things in solving this problem. When I first used this model, I used 2.5 billion data sets. At the time of the error, 90 million data sets were used.

Comment: So I lowered the layer of the model sufficiently and it worked well again.Does this problem occur if the model is too deep for the amount of data? Or did this solve the problem by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving a multi-gpu model, the Keras documentation recommends that you call the `save(fname)` or `save_weights(fname)` methods of the *base* model rather than those of the `multi_gpu_model` (see [here](https://keras.io/utils/), at the very bottom of the page).

I would assign your `multi_gpu_model` to a new variable rather than reassigning `model`. That way you'll have an easy reference to your base model that you can use to save weights.